# Auto Touch Script Coordinates

Tags: android, macros, autotouch

I have a script for auto touch that is set for Nexus 5 (Android Phone), 1080x1920

```
:start
touchDown 0 841 1853
sleep 2.0
touchDown 0 164 371
sleep 2.0
touchDown 0 327 701
sleep 2.0
touchDown 0 841 1853
sleep 2.0
:end
```

I want to convert this script for a resolution for 1306x716. The coordinates has to be changed and I don't know the values to plug in that would fit the resolution of 1306x716. If anyone could kindly help me, that would appreciated.

Comment: Sorry i couldnt put the script in order...the site doesn't let me